# Can I connect a Github Projects task to a commit without converting it to an issue?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, project-management, github-issues

I am trying to use github Projects to manage my dev, but I can't seem to find info anywhere on how to associate a task (NOT an issue) with a commit.  Is there a way to do this similar to how "fix #xxx" line will link to an issue or do I have to convert my tasks to an issue and then close them in my commits in order to do this?  I am familiar with SourceControl and TFS' approach to this but can't find similar functionality in git and I do not have the option to use SourceControl right now.

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE: added screenshot of the webpage display of a Github Project and tasks as an example for clarity.
[image: example of a project as shown kanban style in Github web viewer]

I have tried looking through github documentation, StackExchange, just googling, and digging through the functionalities available when viewing projects. I do use VSCode as my python IDE and the github extensions but perhaps I am missing a particular extension or searching with the wrong keywords.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "task"? A draft issue? An item in a to-do list in an issue description? A task in the (beta) [tasklist feature](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/about-tasklists)?

Comment: I can't add an image, but I will use the url of mine as an example: https://github.com/users/mmfarrugia/projects/4/views/1?layout=board
My understanding of Projects are that they can be linked to a repo (which I've done) and then you can track dev on a project via tasks or to-dos but not necessarily as issues, although you can convert a to-do/task to an issue.  It seems like there is a way to do what I want via automation but I don't necessarily want to deal with that overhead so I'd prefer to just associate commits with a task/to-do in a project

Comment: Your project board is likely private, because that link gives me a 404.

Comment: sorry I meant it as more of an example, I just added a photo to the original post for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot associate a draft issue (project card) without turning it into an issue first.

Instead of creating a draft issue, you could create new issues directly and configure a rule to auto-add them to your project.